# Debian build package: Add python virtualenv into dpkg-buildpackage to be uploaded to launchpad

Tags: python, virtualenv, dpkg

I would like to pack a python program and ship it in a deb package.

For reasons (I know in 99% it is bad practice) I want to ship the program in a python virtual environment within a debian package.

I know I can do this using `dh-virtualenv`. This works great - generally no problem.
But the problem arises when I want to upload this to *launchpad*. Uploading to launchpad means uploading a source package. In terms of `dh-virtualenv` a source package is the package description, where the virtualenv has not been created, yet.

What happens when I upload this to launchpad is, that the package will not build, since the `dh-virtualenv` which is executed during the build process on launchpad will try to install python modules into the virtualenv, which means installing these from the PyPI, which will not work, since launchpad does not allow external network access.

So basically there are two possible solutions:

## Approach A

Prepare the virtualenv and somehow incorporate it into the source package and having the dh build process simply "move" this prepared virtualenv to its end location. This could work with `virtualenv --relocatable`. **BUT** the relocation strips the utf-8 marker at the beginning of all python scripts, rendering all python scripts in the virtualenv broken.

## Apporach B

Somehow *cache* all necessary python packages in the source package and have `dh_virtualenv` install from the cache instead of from PyPI.
This seems like to be doable with `pip2pi`, but certain experiements show, that it will not install packages, although they are located in the local package index.

Both approaches seem a bit clumsy and prone to errors.
What do you think of this?
What are your experiences?
What would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend doing it properly and packaging every dependency separately. Consider that py2deb exists and it helps you creating a skeleton structure from pip dependencies.

Comment: I knew that s.o. would say this. But considering we also want to provide the software on other distros, this would get a fulltime job, which I am currently not willing to take. But thanks for your point of view!

Comment: If you learn proper packaging, you'll find out that it's easier than your own hand written scripts. (I contribute to Debian).

Comment: Also, are you still using python2?

Comment: @LtWorf I have no time to explain the above mentioned many reasons and you are obviously not interested in. Anyway thanks for your time to comment on this.

Comment: Yes I'm not interested in replying to people who don't have time to ask a question properly.